# Extract data from JSONs inside the CSV

Tags: python, json, csv, filter, extract

Could you advise what would be the best way to extract an element from JSON when I have multiple JSONs in a CSV file?

The data structure is like this

`Line1: {"CreationTime":"2018-10-29T13:40:13","Id":"35127aae-a888-4665-6514-08d63da40e14","Operation":....,"IPaddress":"x.x.x.x"...}
Line 2: {"CreationTime":"2018-10-29T13:41:13","Id":"35127aae-a888-4665-6514-08d63da40e14","Operation":....,"IPAddress":"x.x.x.x"...}
.....
LineYY:...`

My goal is to extract the `IPAddress` value from every line, that means from every json array. What would be the best way to do it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please slow the exact data in the file.

Comment: Check out ‘pandas.read_json’ with ‘lines=True’

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `json` to load each line into a dictionary and then access `IPAddress`

```
import json
ips = []
for line in data.readlines():
    row = json.loads(line)
    ips.append(row['IPAddress'])
```

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking into that direction. Appreciate the example.

Comment: Welcome, accept the answer if it solves the problem.

Comment: I get an error on the `row = json.loads(line)`. It complains about the `ValueError: Extra data: line 1 column 4 - line 2 column 1 (char 3 - 1108)`